# How to join two tables with many-to-many relation using vlookup in Excel?

Tags: database, excel, excel-formula

I have a data model between three entities (tables):

```
Field
Screen
Window
```

`Window-Screen` has many-to-many relationship. So, I defined a join table `Screen_Window` with foreign keys to both tables.

`Screen-Field` has one-to-many relationship. So, each `Screen` has many Fields. But each `Field` belongs to one `Screen` record.

Now, I want to build a report that will join `Fields` to their corresponding `Windows`.

A sample data from `Screen_Window`:

```
(column A) (column B) 
screen_id  window_id  
s1         w1         
s2         w1         
s1         w2
```

The expected report should be like that:

```
(column D) (column E) (column F) 
field_id   screen_id  window_id  
f1         s1         w1         
f1         s1         w2
```

I use the `VLOOKUP` function in `column F` in order to produce this report:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2;A2:B4;2)
```

The result is the following:

```
(column D) (column E) (column F) 
field_id   screen_id  window_id  
f1         s1         w1
```

So, `VLOOKUP` ignores the `w2` record:

```
f1         s1         w2
```

How can I produce the expected report automatically in Excel?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` returnes only the first record. Have a look at `INDEX`

Comment: Excel is typically inappropriate for handling multiple one to many relationship.   Most of its built in functions (such as VLOOKUP) are designed to return one value, so there is no simple way to create a spreadsheet that creates a variable number of rows depending on the content of one to many relationships.   A solution in Excel would require VBA macros to loop through data with logic to create new rows. This is not really a SQL question.

Comment: Why not toss this data in a database? It would be solved with a simple `SELECT field_id, screen_id, window_it FROM field JOIN screen ON field.screen_id = screen.screen_id JOIN window ON screen.window_id = window.window_id` I think the effort to import your data into Access, or really any DB would outweigh the work necessary to pull off Set manipulation in Excel.

Comment: @JNevill I can solve this problem using SQL or R. But I wanted to check if this can also be solved in Excel because some team members in our project don't know neither SQL nor R. Excel is a very useful tool. It is a pity that it cannot join one-to-many relationships properly.

Answer (score 0):

The VLOOKUP() formula can't make it but you can still use excel to work with it using the following array formula:

```
{=+INDEX($B$2:$B$12,SMALL(IF(E2=$A$2:$A$12,ROW($A$2:$A$12)-ROW($A$2)+1),COUNTIF($E$2:E2,E2)))}
```

In order to make the formula an array formula you have to use **"Ctrl + Shift + Enter"** keys together instead of "Enter" only.

I tried in an example and works:

[image: Example]